# AndroidX causing AppCompatActivity to crash

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

The application was running just fine until all of a sudden this error got triggered somehow :

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:543)
> ```

```
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
    at com.thorsguild.company..Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
```

I should mention that I just started using [this library from GitHub](https://github.com/nex3z/ToggleButtonGroup) which serve as a group toggle button and was about to test it

**Q:** What does this error mean and how to fix it ??

**UPDATE**

*Entire Stack trace*

```
2019-05-31 12:04:14.216 14753-14753/com.hablo.company.hablo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hablo.company.hablo, PID: 14753
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hablo.company.hablo/com.hablo.company.hablo.Activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #126: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class com.nex3z.togglebuttongroup.button.CircularButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #126: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class com.nex3z.togglebuttongroup.button.CircularButton
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class com.nex3z.togglebuttongroup.button.CircularButton
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nex3z.togglebuttongroup.button.CircularButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.hablo.company.hablo-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1011)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:873)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
2019-05-31 12:04:14.216 14753-14753/com.hablo.company.hablo E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:543)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
    at com.hablo.company.hablo.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2900)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and post the entire stack trace, not just three lines from the middle of it.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the quick tip, I added the entire stack trace

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nex3z.togglebuttongroup.button.CircularButton"` -- do you have a typo in the class name?

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah that was it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have misread the class name. You are supposed to use `CircularToggle` but you are using `CircularButton` which is not there in library. You can check the sample usage mentioned on github which is as below

```
<com.nex3z.togglebuttongroup.button.CircularToggle
        android:id="@+id/choice_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"/>
```

Comment: yes that's exactly the case, it's actually `CircularToggle` not `CircularButton` !

Comment: @ThorvaldÓlavsenV. you should mark this answer then :)